# Can I have webpack output be a string instead of JS

Tags: webpack

I am trying to use Webpack so that I can inject HTML into a properties file (please no lecture on how insecure that is :-)) I tried to use the following configuration...

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  context:"",
  entry: {
    projects: path.join(__dirname, "../other/src/properties")
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.pre.properties',
      '.html',
      '.htm'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].properties",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "../other/src")
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["to-string-loader", "html-loader?interpolate=require&-minimize"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.properties$/,
        use: ["raw-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

The problem is that it still wraps everything in the JS as opposed to a raw string. Can I output from Webpack as a raw string?

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using Webpack 2 I could create a wrapper JS like this...

```
var a = require("./projects.pre.properties");
```

Then I configured the ExtractTextPlugin...

```
new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name].properties',
  allChunks: true,
}),
```